# Unable read EDID on CRT-0 (VGA port) - Nvidia GeForce 8600M GT

Tags: linux, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

My work laptop is a Dell Vostro 1500. It has a Nvidia GeForce 8600M GT gpu. I always like having a second monitor plugged in, but it never detects monitor resolutions correctly.

In the Xorg.0.log, I see :

```
[    22.992] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
```

I have the problem with both the proprietary Nvidia driver, and the Nouveau driver.

I have previously just accepted that it does not work and have manually configured the modelines in xorg.conf/xrandr command line. Yesterday I discovered that on my colleague's laptop, which is also a Vostro 1500 with a Nvidia GeForce 8600M GT, the edid works.

Any suggestions on how to get the edid to work. (Please don't tell me to set the modelines manually. I know how to do this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a hardware problem. I got a new issue with the graphics card, and got Dell to replace the graphics card, and the edid problem got fixed when they did this.